# generic regex for between two parts

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a regex which gets the part between two other things using PHP.

I have:

```
RANDOMSTUFFpart1CONTENTpart2RANDOMSTUFF2
```

So I want to extract CONTENT from between part1 and part2.

Is there a generic regex expression that I can use, where I just add in code for part1 and part2 and it will work?

Something like:

```
$part1='';
$part2='';
$string='RANDOMSTUFFpart1CONTENTpart2RANDOMSTUFF2';
$regexthing=...
```

**I don't know if Dimitri will return to edit his answer, so I will put the corrected solution here:**

```
$part1 = 'part1';
$part2 = 'part2';
$string = 'RANDOMSTUFFpart1CONTENTpart2RANDOMSTUFF2';
$pattern = '/' . $part1 . '(.*?)' . $part2 . '/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Yes, if nothing may be between two parts use (.*?)

```
$part1 = 'part1';
$part2 = 'part2';
$string = 'RANDOMSTUFFpart1CONTENTpart2RANDOMSTUFF2';
$pattern = '/' . $part1 . '(.*?)' . $part2 . '/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that there's anything in between `part1` and `part2`, so I'd change it from `.+?` to `.*?`. There's a difference between "nothing in between" and "not found".

Comment: What is the difference between .+? and .*?

Comment: Also, you might want to use `$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($part1) . '(.+?)' . preg_quote($part2) . '/';` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/part1(.*?)part2/
```

The `.*?` will match any characters up until the very first occurence of 'part2'